# Erlang adding userdefined Symbols like ** or <*

Tags: erlang

I wanted to add some more symbols to my Erlang library. Example 
For a matrix library A**B could mean matrix multiplication etc. 
I could not find any help for the same. 
Also anyone knows how to apply functions like + - or % using erlang:apply()

Comment: It would be neat if Erlang allowed arbitrary infix symbols, but Erlang don't; without real symbol support, using symbols as function names has a tendency to look cluttered imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any atom as function name. If you have specail symbols in atom you have to use its quoted form `'**'`:

```
-module(operator).
-export(['**'/2]).

'**'(A, B) ->
    {'**', A, B}.
```

There is no syntactic sugar to use such operators though. All the default operators are functions defined in module `erlang` and can be accessed like that:

```
1> operator:'**'(a, b).
{'**',a,b}
2> F0 = fun operator:'**'/2.
#Fun<operator.**.2>
3> F0(c, d).
{'**',c,d}
4> F1 = fun erlang:'+'/2.
#Fun<erlang.+.2>
5> F1(1, 2).
3
6> F2 = fun erlang:'rem'/2.
#Fun<erlang.rem.2>
7> F2(5, 3).
2
```

Comment: Yup, one other cool example is finding the sum or product of a list with `lists:foldl(fun erlang:'+'/2,0,lists:seq(1,10))` or `lists:foldl(fun erlang:'*'/2,1,lists:seq(1,10))`.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want this you can use a parse transform but your code has to be syntactically correct before the transform. So for example your parse transform can rewrite `A *_* B` into `exp(A, B)` because `A *_* B` will be parsed as something like `(A * _) * B`. However you will not be able to transform `A ** B`.

Also, using parse transforms for something so frivolous is a really bad idea.